# My batch script is reporting an error stating "was unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file

The Windows batch file I am trying to run contains the following assignment:

```
set ANT_HOME="C:/Program Files/apache-ant-1.8.4"
```

The offending line is:

```
call %ANT_HOME%/bin/ant -f ../config/common.xml start_db
```

And when I run the script with echo on I get:

```
call "C:/Program_Files/apache-ant-1.8.4"/bin/ant -f ../config/common.xml start_db
Files/apache-ant-1.8.4""=="" was unexpected at this time.
```

I've moved the second quote to to the end of the path, after the ant, but I receive the same error message.

Comment: I think you have an unwanted underscore in your example output - `Program_Files` should read `Program Files`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If ant were an .exe I would say your code should work. But I suspect that ant is a batch file, and the error is occurring within the ant script.

I base my conclusion on your error message - specifically the following portion of it: `""==""`. The error message is a batch parsing error, and I don't see how your code could generate those characters. So I figure ant must be a batch script that is causing the problem.

I suspect ant.bat has `@echo off` at the top, so you are not seeing the actual line that is failing.

Not having access to the ant.bat script, I couldn't possibly diagnose exactly what is failing, nor can I guess on how to fix it.

**Update - exact problem found**

I found a copy of [ant.bat](http://svn.rifers.org/rife-search/trunk/lib/ant-1.6.2/bin/ant.bat) online.

It has the following line of code within:

```
if "%ANT_HOME%"=="" set ANT_HOME=%DEFAULT_ANT_HOME%
```

Your definition of ANT_HOME includes enclosing quotes, so the code is trying to execute

```
if ""C:/Program Files/apache-ant-1.8.4""=="" set ANT_HOME=%DEFAULT_ANT_HOME%
```

The space is not quoted, and you have your error.

All you need to do to fix everything is to remove the quotes from the definition of ANT_HOME, and then add quotes to your CALL statement:

```
set "ANT_HOME=C:/Program Files/apache-ant-1.8.4"
call "%ANT_HOME%/bin/ant" -f ../config/common.xml start_db
```

Forward-slashes are not always reliable as folder delimiters within Windows. See [Why does the cmd.exe shell on Windows fail with paths using a forward-slash ('/'') path separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523708/why-does-the-cmd-exe-shell-on-windows-fail-with-paths-using-a-forward-slash).

Better to use back-slashes.

```
set "ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.4"
call "%ANT_HOME%\bin\ant" -f ..\config\common.xml start_db
```

Comment: Also, sorry about the extra underscore in the output. That was from a debug attempt.  I reverted the forward slashes back to the original back slashes and with the quotes in the correct location, encompassing the variable name, the script worked like a champ.  I am so impressed with quick and knowledgeable response provided to my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The quotes have to completely surround a file name.  You can't use them for partial names.  Try this instead:

```
set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.4
call "%ANT_HOME%\bin\ant" -f ../config/common.xml start_db
```

Oh, and I changed some of your slashes to backslashes (DOS doesn't like forward slashes).  I assume you are allowed to use `/` in that parameter you are passing though.

Comment: Edited to comment on usage of backslash versus ordinary slash.

Comment: Wrong on both counts - You can use quotes around partial names, even multiple times within the same path. The quotes protect spaces and special characters, and then are discarded. Give it a try :-)  Also, forward slashes often work, though it seems to be bugged. CALL seems to support forward slash based on a few quick tests I just ran. See [Why does the cmd.exe shell on Windows fail with paths using a forward-slash path separator?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10526678/1012053) for examples that don't involve CALL that work and fail.

Comment: Your suggested edits fix the problem, but not for the reasons you state. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12666896/1012053).

Comment: Glad you fixed it.  For the record, in most batch files I've seen the empty-test is done like this: `if %ANT_HOME%.==.`

Comment: Actually, the safest test is `if not defined ANT_HOME`. But probably should not modify the 3rd party ant.bat file.