# Python setuptools is stripping slashes from path arguments on Windows

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to install a package with `setuptools` including `console_scripts` on Windows 7. I'm trying to change the value of my `PYTHONUSERBASE` to install into a custom directory with the `--user` flag. If I use backslashes in the value of `PYTHONUSERBASE`, as in

```
set PYTHONUSERBASE=C:\testing
```

everything works fine. However, if I use a forward slash, as in

```
set PYTHONUSERBASE=C:/testing
```

the package itself installs to the right place, but the `console_scripts` (and only the `console_scripts`) are installed into `C:testing\Scripts`. Obviously, when the forward slash is present, `setuptools` is treating the path as a relative path **only for the `console_scripts`**. In my real package, I'm reading values from a configuration file, so I would really rather not have to deal with normalizing the path separator since it needs to work on Linux as well. For testing, I have a package with the structure

```
|-- setup.py
|-- foobar\
|---- __init__.py
|---- __main__.py
```

The code in the `__main__.py` is

```
def main(): print('This is the main function')
```

and `setup.py` looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='foobar',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=['foobar'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foobar=foobar.__main__:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

Why is `setuptools` stripping out the first forward slash in the path and how can I fix it? I think this question is related to my problem, but I don't think it solves it: [Python os.path.join on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422798/python-os-path-join-on-windows)

Comment: I have no idea why setuptools is doing this, but you might be able to do something in your setup function like `if 'PYTHONUSERBASE' in os.environ: os.environ['PYTHONUSERBASE'] = os.environ['PYTHONUSERBASE'].replace('/', os.sep)`

Comment: @PatrickMaupin I was thinking of something like that... I actually use SCons to build the real project, so I was trying to see if I could handle it in the SConstruct file as well. I think it would probably be better to use `os.path.normpath` rather than explicitly replace the slashes though. Thanks!

Comment: It's a plan.  I forget normpath() will do that because it's windows-specific behavior (on linux, it won't change backslashes into slashes) and I don't use windows.  Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that Windows doesn't work well with forward slashes in the path name - as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523708/why-does-the-cmd-exe-shell-on-windows-fail-with-paths-using-a-forward-slash).  Avoid setting the PYTHONUSERBASE environment variable with such a name.

The longer version is that setuptools normalizes most of its path names (which converts / to \ on Windows versions of Python) either directly or by calling abs path.  However it does not do so for the directory name which it uses when creating scripts (see write_script in [this file](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/acb8319982f13971962e94d77a71c79befce87c4/setuptools/command/easy_install.py?at=default)).

You therefore see inconsistent behavior between scripts and other files.  The fix is to avoid needing to normalize the files by avoiding the forward slashes in your paths.

If you're reading the path from a config file and then using that to set PYTHONUSERBASE simply use os.path.normpath to convert from Linux to Windows file names.  This is fine on Linux as it will have no effect on the slashes.

Comment: Arguably a bug in `write_script()` I'd say.  Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty much where I ended up, using `normpath` to fix the problem. I agree with @JRichardSnape though, that this seems like a bug in `write_script()`, or at least, it should be documented...