# Why is full path of files found in a directory specified with a relative path using wildcard pattern *.xls in a FOR loop wrong?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I have a batch file to process each Excel file found by **FOR** with a wildcard pattern with a Java application:

```
for %%i in ("../test data/sprint4/*.xls") do (
    @echo "%%~fi"
)
```

I am running this batch file for example from

```
C:\dir1\dir2\dir3
```

and there is the file

```
C:\dir1\dir2\test data\sprint4\myfile.xlx
```

The output file name with full path is

```
C:\dir1\dir2\myfile.xls
```

`test data\sprint4` is missing in the path and I am not sure what is wrong.

Someone suggested using `/?`, but when I do `echo /?` there is a very limited amount of information:

> echo /?
>   Displays messages, or turns command-echoing on or off.
>
> ECHO [ON | OFF]
>     ECHO [message]
>
> Type ECHO without parameters to display the current echo setting.

This really does not explain usage of wildcards. Searches did not help either. So now I am stuck.

Why is full path of Excel files found in a directory specified with a relative path using wildcard pattern *.xls in above FOR loop wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use backslashes for Window's paths instead of forward slashes.

```
for %%i in ("..\test data\sprint4\*.xls") do (
    @echo "%%~fi"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Run in a command prompt window `for /?` to get output the several display pages long help for this command.

And the directory separator on Windows is `\` and not `/` whereby Windows command interpreter often (but not always) corrects this as it can be seen on running the batch file from within a command prompt because command interpreter prints to console what is really processed after parsing a command line respectively command block. In this case the slashes are not automatically corrected to backslashes resulting in wrong paths for the found files.

However, full path finding of command **FOR** is sometimes not working as expected from relative paths. The code in question is one example.

Solution 1 is using predefined environment variable **CD** containing path of Current Directory not ending with a backslash except the current directory is the root of a drive which can't occur here.

```
for %%i in ("%CD%\..\test data\sprint4\*.xls") do (
    @echo "%%~fi"
)
```

The current directory can be different to directory of the batch file.

Solution 2 is using drive and path of the batch file referenced with `%~dp0` whereby this path always ends with a backslash.

```
for %%i in ("%~dp0..\test data\sprint4\*.xls") do (
    @echo "%%~fi"
)
```

Run in a command prompt window `call /?` for details on `%~dp0` and `set /?` for details on **CD** and other predefined environment variables.

Solution 3 is using relative path, but with backslashes:

```
for %%i in ("..\test data\sprint4\*.xls") do (
    @echo "%%~fi"
)
```

Now name of found *.xls files are always with correct full path.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you should use `\` instead of `/`, and that solves your problem.

As to why `/` fails...
There are a number of contexts where `/` works, and some where it does not, and some where it appears to work, but gives the wrong result. See [Why does the cmd.exe shell on Windows fail with paths using a forward-slash ('/'') path separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10523708/1012053).

You have discovered another case where it "works", but gives the wrong result. The problem is that `%%i` while using `/` gives the found file name and extension only, so when you ask for the full path with `%%~fi`, it uses the current directory, and you get your wrong result.

```
for %%i in ("../test data/sprint4/*.xls") do @echo "%%i" --^> "%%~fi"
```

yields:

```
"myfile.xlx" -->  "C:\dir1\dir2\test data\sprint4\myfile.xlx"
```

But if you switch to back slashes, then the original relative path is preserved, so `%%~fi` gives the correct result:

```
for %%i in ("..\test data\sprint4\*.xls") do @echo "%%i" --^> "%%~fi"
```

yields:

```
"..\test data\sprint4\myfile.xlx" --> "C:\dir1\dir2\test data\sprint4\myfile.xlx"
```

On my machine, I seem to get the correct answer with the FOR loop if my path contains at least one `\`. But I would not rely on that because there are [so many cases where `/` can fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526678/1012053). Best to get in the habit of always using `\` in all cases.

Comment: I guess it is just a psychological thing for me with a unix/linux background, \ always escapes characters ;-)  This gets to be a big problem in java.  Sometimes you have to use \\\\.  But cmd is different so I will replace the / with \